# Which html tags to use for this output

Tags: html

I cannot figure out which HTML tags to use to get the format below. Can someone tell me which ones to use?

```
Fruit:      $ 10,000
Apples:     $ 4,000
Orange:     $ 6,000
```

Comment: You can use any tag. `<h1>`, `<p>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any tag that you want

```html
<p>Fruit:      $10,000</p>
<p>Apples:     $4,000</p>
<p>Orange:     $6,000</p>
```

```html
<h1>Fruit:      $10,000</h1>
<h1>Apples:     $4,000</h1>
<h1>Orange:     $6,000</h1>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the data will be variables from my php program.  I don't know how to get the numeric data aligned.

Answer (score 0):

To get the dollar numbers aligned, you could either just use a table:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fruit:</td>
    <td>$10,000</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples:</td>
    <td>$4,000</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oranges:</td>
    <td>$6,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or you make div elements:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%">Fruit:</div>$10,000
<div style="width: 50%">Apples:</div>$4,000
<div style="width: 50%">Oranges:</div>$6,000
```

I would definitely use the first version as the style can be changed way easier and it's easier to maintain (you can easily add lines, a table structure, the width, the number of columns, etc.) while you need to code the second example new if you want to change the design, the number of columns, etc.
Nevertheless, both option are good and I hope I could help you.